# How to disable message button on lockscreen?

Tags: sms

Hello I want to make this button gone, because I installed lockscreen notifications app, but if I disable in messages app notifications it not notificate when I get new message.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my device you can change or get rid of them by this way: Settings-> Security-> Shortcuts

Comment: Where's no such thing as shortcuts. Only Screen lock, owner info, encrypt phone, set up sim card lock, make passwords visible, device administrators, unknown sources, verify apps, trusted crediantials, install from sd card, clear crediancials

Comment: What about Settings -> My device -> Lock screen -> Screen lock? Select swipe, turn shortcuts on and click on the word shortcuts.

Comment: No my device.
http://www.part.lt/img/0a3c950b2ab8af6d23f7dda6a046635b829.png /
http://www.part.lt/img/70cf1ff962ad0679e813d6ee9ab8c558390.png /
http://www.part.lt/img/113c97dbaf6b21fb41c44c94dd8d70d8954.png